# jQuery: Repeated (undesired) fading in/out in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I am just now beginning to explore jQuery (v1.4.2) and have constructed a small, static example for purposes of self-education.

I'm using Firefox 3.6.9, Chromium 6.0.472.53 and Opera 10.61 on the Linux platform.

I find that my example works as expected on Chromium and Opera, but I get a very annoying flickering behavior of jQuery fadeIn happening twice on Firefox.

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced the same issue or if there are any known workarounds.

Here's the code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
function showA1()
{
  $.get("zh1.html", function(data){$("#mainDiv").html(data);});
}
function showB2()
{
  $.get("zh2.html", function(data){$("#mainDiv").html(data);});
}
function clickA1()
{
  $("#mainDiv").fadeOut(showB2);
  $("#mainDiv").fadeIn();
}
function clickB2()
{
  $("#mainDiv").fadeOut(showA1);
  $("#mainDiv").fadeIn();
}
function executeWhenReady()
{
  showA1();
}
$(document).ready(executeWhenReady);
```

zh1.html

```
<div>Button A1</div><a href="javascript:clickA1();"><button id=A1>First button</button></a>
```

zh2.html

```
<div>Button B2</div><a href="javascript:clickB2();"><button id=B2>Second button</button></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to doubt that this issue is linked to Firefox itself, but rather that maybe you're just noticing it in Firefox more.  I think the problem is probably an issue of timing with your $.get call and .fadeIn().  Something to bear in mind...

```
$("#mainDiv").fadeOut(showA1);
$("#mainDiv").fadeIn();
```

These two lines queue up two functions - fadeOut and then fadeIn.  However, you're trying to switch the content somewhere in the middle.

Fade it out -> Bring in the new content -> Fade it back in

What you're not accounting for is the fact that bringing in new content can take time.  I suggest you refactor things like so.

```
function showA1()
{
  $.get("zh1.html", function(data){
    var $blk = $("#mainDiv");
    $blk.html(data);
    // only try to fadeIn the container if it's hidden (as it won't be hidden on initial page load when you call showA1)
    $blk.is(':hidden') && $blk.fadeIn();
  });
}
function showB2()
{
  $.get("zh2.html", function(data){
    $("#mainDiv").html(data).fadeIn();
  });
}
function clickA1()
{
  $("#mainDiv").fadeOut(showB2);
}
function clickB2()
{
  $("#mainDiv").fadeOut(showA1);
}
```

It makes it so that the fadeIn operation isn't queued up until after the html of #mainDiv has been changed.